# Declare a template pointer without knowing the type

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I have this code with a template function. The function can accept any object that is inherited from Object or with an operator providing a pointer to an Object instance. Inside the function I need to get the Object pointer, but it is a template type and I can't figure out the way how to specify the template type.

here is the code:

```
class IObject
{
};

template<class T>
class Object: public IObject
{
    typedef T value_type;
public:
    void test()
    {
    }
    operator Object<T>*()
    {
        return this;
    }
};

template<class T>
class Wrapper
{
    typedef T value_type;
public:
    T object;
    operator T*()
    {
        return &object;
    }
};


template<class T>
class Container
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        data.resize(1);
        typename T::value_type& ref = data[0];
        //IObject* object = ref; //works
        Object<?>* object = ref; // How can I specify the template type here?
        object->test();
    };
    T data;
};

int main()
{       
    Container<std::vector<Object<float>>> container1;
    container1.func();
    Container<std::vector<Wrapper<Object<int>>>> container2;
    container2.func();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried playing with value_type, but as there are technically 2 types of objects can be used as an input, it doesn't work. Also I tried adding extra argument to the function template, but the argument type can't be deduced by the compiler.

Comment: I don't get what the purpose of Object<T> is. It doesn't hold any data.

Comment: You can use `auto* object = ptr;`

Comment: it's a simplified example

Comment: I don't understand the "This works" comment. It doesn't work for `object3` or `object4`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, the question is still unclear(at least to me) about what exactly OP wants. I mean which call should work and what is the expected output etc.

Comment: I updated the example it compiles now

Comment: Why don't you take a `Object<T>&` as parameter instead of a `T&`? Also `ptr` is not a pointer, it's clearly a reference.

Comment: In this example it would be possible, but in my case it is inside a template container (std::vector>) inside a template class, so I can get Object<float> or Wrapper<Object<int>> only as T::value_type of this vector. I'll update the example to be more specific

Comment: Then just use a custom type trait to get a `Object<T>` from a typename. Is that what your question is about?

Comment: I don't see how type traits can be used here, could you give an example? I updated the code

Comment: In Wrapper class, the user-define function should be `operator T*()` as T is the `Object` type already, also `T object;`

Comment: Is `Container` supposed to accept any standard container?

Comment: Not any but some Qt and std containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, either your `Wrapper` is wrong or your usage of it is wrong. You instantiate `Wrapper<Object<int>>` but in the class you have:

```
Object<T> object;
operator Object<T>*()
```

which is instantiated as

```
Object<Object<int>> object;
operator Object<Object<int>>*()
```

You should either instantiate `Wrapper<int>`, which would "wrap" a `Object<int>`, or change your class to have this instead:

```
T object;
operator T*()
```

but then the `typedef T value_type` is wrong.

In any case, you can create a type trait to "unwrap" the type:

```
template<class T>
struct UnwrapT {
    using type = T;
};

template<class T>
struct UnwrapT<Wrapper<T>> {
    using type = Object<T>;
};

template<class T>
using Unwrap = typename UnwrapT<T>::type;
```

You can then use this in `func`:

```
Unwrap<typename T::value_type>* object = ref;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4G6bvTPof)